# Find out expected value and dispersion of min($\xi,\eta$)

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

The task: $\xi$ and $\eta$- independent random variables. $\xi$ is 
evenly distributed on [0,1] and $\eta$ 
takes values 0 and 1 ​​with probability of 1/2. Find out expected value and dispersion of min($\xi,\eta$).

I have already find out the distribution function $F_{\zeta} =1-P((min(\xi,\eta)\geqslant t)=1-(1-P(\xi<t))(1-P(\eta<t))$, but I have no ideas how to find exp value and dispesion without Lebesgue integral.

Comment: "Dispersion" = "Variance"?

Comment: @ConnorHarris, Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X = \min(\xi, \eta)$. There's a $1/2$ chance that $\eta = 0$, in which case $E(X|\eta = 0) = E(X^2|\eta = 0) = 0$, and there's a $1/2$ chance that $\eta = 1$, in which case $E(X | \eta = 1) = E(\xi) = 1/2$ and $E(X^2 | \eta = 1) = E(\xi^2) = \int_0^1 x^2\, dx = 1/3$. Putting these together gives $E(X) = 1/4$ and $E(X^2) = 1/6$, and the variance of $X$ is $E(X^2) - E(X)^2 = 5/48$.

Comment: We get E(X) as E($\xi$)*P($\eta=1$)?

Comment: Basically there are two cases of equal probability: $\eta = X = 0$, or $\eta = 1$ and $X = \xi$. We can compute $E(X)$ by taking the average of those two cases.

Comment: Thank you very much!